# Fuzzy substring matching in a string Lucene.NET

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net, fuzzy-search

I've just installed Lucene.NET.

I'm doing a text search.
I want to check if a large text contains / fuzzy matches a word/phrase, say:

Eg1:

text: 
"I posted a question about Lucene.NET on stackoverflow. Will I get an asnwer?"

textToSearch: "posted a question abot Lucene"

These 2 should be a match, since text contains textToSearch (except the samll typo abot -> about.

Is this possible with Lucene.NET library?

If not, does it support at least single word fuzzy matching in a text?

Eg:

text: "I posted a question on stackoverflow"

textToSearch "stackovrlow" (missspelled)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lucene.Net supports single fuzzy matching in a text. You could do it with the help of [FuzzyQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d0/db9/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_fuzzy_query.html).

Unfortunately, you could only somehow mimic the behavior of the first example. One possible solution is to create big [BooleanQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d8/d7c/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_boolean_query.html) with each clause being [FuzzyQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d0/db9/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_fuzzy_query.html), but this will lead to poor performance, as well, as it will lose the order of the terms.

Another possibility is to use [SpanNearQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/dc9/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_spans_1_1_span_near_query.html) which will help to store the positions (you could specify the needed slop), but there is no possibility to add FuzzyQuery as clauses (you could only somehow try to use [SpanRegexQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d6/d56/class_contrib_1_1_regex_1_1_span_regex_query.html))

Answer (score 1):

Mysterion is right, that Span Queries can be helpful, but wrong in saying the FuzzyQueries cannot be used. That is what [SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0//core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.html) is for. Something like this:

```
SpanQuery query = new SpanNearQuery.Builder("myField", true).
    .addClause(new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("myField", "question"))))
    .addClause(new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("myField", "abot"))))
    .addClause(new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("myField", "lucene"))))
    .build();
```

Remember, by the way, when manually constructing queries (rather than using a queryparser), you need to take analysis into account, as they will not be run through an analyzer.

Comment: you're right in general Lucene, but unfortunately, it's not true for Lucene.Net, since Lucene.Net is a very outdated version of java Lucene

Comment: @Mysterion - Ah, you are right, my mistake. Was thinking it was up to 4.X, but that's apparently [still in beta](http://code972.com/blog/2016/07/98-lucene-net-4-8-is-in-beta-and-we-need-your-help).